# Unable to get auto enrolled certificates from AD CS (certificate authority) server

Tags: active-directory, ca, certificate-authority

Our domain structure has two AD sites, S1 and S2; AD Forest has one root domain and one child domain.
The issuing CA (Active directory certificate service) is installed in the management server in child domain. The child domain DCs (both from S1 and S2 sites) are getting auto enrolled certificates from CA server. The root domain DCs from S1 site is getting auto enrolled certificates from the CA server.
**Issue**: The root domain DCs from S2 site does not get the auto enrolled certificates from the CA server.
I have checked the following ports connectivity. Telnet from CA to DCs (both root and child domains, both S1 and S2 sites) on ports 464, 389, 636 is good. Telnet from DCs (both root and child domains, both S1 and S2 sites) to CA on ports 443, 80, 135 is good. Can you please provide directions to fix this.

Comment: How are you configuring the auto enrollment? If using Group Policy, perhaps the GPO used in the root domain is linked to the S1 site rather than the domain/domain controllers OU?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I see the GPO is linked to  Forest_name > Domains > Domain_name > 'Default domain policy'. I did gpresult /h and can see 'Default domain policy' is the winning gpo on the DCs (for both Sites S1 and S2) in root domain.

Following is the policy: 
Automatic certificate management - Enabled. Enroll new certificates, renew expired certificates, process pending certificate requests and remove revoked certificates - Enabled. Update and manage certificates that use certificate templates from Active Directory - Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can try running the below command on the DC that is not retrieving the auto enrollment certificate from the child domain CA server. This command checks for any certificate templates that the system has permission on and enroll them successfully if the permissions settings on the certificate template are correctly configured.

```
      ‘ certutil -pulse ‘   or   ‘ certutil -pulse -<user>  ‘
```

Where  is the domain admin user that has permissions on the certificate template that must be auto enrolled.

•   Also, check the certificate template type for the domain controller whether it is ‘Domain Controller Authentication’ type or ‘Domain Controller’ type that is requesting for auto enrollment. Please ensure that the certificate enrollment for the root DC is not present in the list of failed requests on the CA. To check this, log onto the CA and open the command prompt and enter the following the commands to check for the same: -

```
        ‘ certutil -view LogFail ’ --> This will present the requests that are failed for certificate enrollment

        ‘ certutil -view -restrict requestID=“<requestID from the above request detail>” ’
```

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/dd299884(v=ws.10)